# $_REQUEST in PHP

Tags: php, request

I have this code.

```
$message = "";

if($_REQUEST['msg'] == "new"){
    $message = "New User has been added successfully";
}else if($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'edit'){
    $message = "User has been saved successfully";
}else if($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'update'){
    $message = "User(s) has been Updated successfully";
}
```

can any one please tell me here what is **['msg']** and please explain the functioning of $_REQUEST?

Comment: `msg` is the name of the form element, something like `<input name="msg" value="new" />` would match that

Comment: PHP does have documentation you know: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Sir i know ..........but i m unable to understand this. i want it in simple language.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is a superglobal which contains data available from HTML forms.   Note:   If you are looking for more simple tutorials  you might find that this site is very useful if you are having a hard time reading official manuals.   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) is a superglobal array that is (from the PHP documentation):

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET,
> $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, and `$_SESSION`, it can store a list of information associatively. In the case of `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST`, and `$_GET` these arrays will store encoded data sent to the PHP header.

Example of what might be contained (not recommended to set it like this though):

```
$_REQUEST['key1'] = 'value1';
$_REQUEST['streetAddress'] = '123 Baker St';
```

Or here is an example of a link that would populate it from a GET parameter:
`<a href='?key=value'>value</a> // for $_GET and $_REQUEST`

PHP will grab that key->value from the URL and save it to the superglobal array that you are using. To access it call:
`echo $_REQUEST['key']; // displays 'value'`

In your case msg is, so far, not send by the browser. It needs to be passed by a different means (forms, href's etc.). So,

```
 $_REQUEST['msg'] = 'new'; // not recommended to actually set it directly, purely illustrative of it already being set to something
 if (isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) { // use isset() to avoid an error
    if ($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'new') {
        $message = 'New User has been added successfully';  
    } elseif ($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'edit') {
        $message = 'User has been saved successfully';
    } elseif ($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'update') {
        $message = 'User(s) has been Updated successfully';
    }
} // sets $message = "New user..."
```

Using `$_REQUEST` is not recommended. It goes against best practices because it makes it hard to control what information is processed. GET parameters, POST parameters, and cookies all serve different purposes. It is better to decide which of those the data you want to process should come from and use either `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_COOKIE` accordingly. `$_GET` requests show the key->value pairs in the URL. Information that you don't want as visible probably shouldn't be shown there. GET is appropriate for indicating what the user is accessing, when doing so does not amount to actions/changes being requested. POST is better for parameters involved when the user is requesting some action be taken, such as updating data or sending an email. Using GET instead of POST when appropriate makes it less likely a user will accidently re-request a change/action just by hitting back or bookmarking a page (such as purchasing something a second time by accident), although it doesn't completely eliminate that possibility as it depends on whether their browser re-sends the POST data in those cases.

If you use `$_REQUEST` for everything, a user can send key->value pairs over the URL to see what information needs to be passed and exploit that in other ways (google cross-site request forgeries). Using the more specific $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE variables instead makes it a little harder for them to attempt this. However, using these does not actually protect you, as your are still processing either GET parameters, POST parameters, or cookies sent by the user. Even so, it is better to restrict which of those the code will process in different scenarios. Ultimately you will still need to use proper techniques to protect against processing user provided values in a dangerous way, but that is a separate topic.

TL;DR : `$_REQUEST['msg']` -- 'msg' is a key in a key->value pair ('new'| 'edit' | 'update' being the value). `$_REQUEST` is a superglobal array that contains GET, POST, and cookie keys and values sent by the user's browser or other client. It can be accessed from any part of the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

$_REQUEST contains values passed by post,get and/or cookies. As get is easy to hack so safer mechanism would be to use post when send data from one html/php file to another. Then you need to use $_POST to get the data. More detail you can find from this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp).

So in your case previous html page has used either of the techniques to use a variable/parameter/cookie named msg to pass data.

Answer (score 1):

The $_REQUEST['msg'] is a key from the superglobal array.
Basically $_REQUEST will access it even if the variable was sent through $_POST or $_GET :

$_POST : 
$_GET : page.php?msg=testMsg